# Logical error when I'm calculate ROI (unexpected output)

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: here you can see there are three items with wrong ROI]

```
ROI = 
VAR _NetIncome = SUMX('historical-sales', 'historical 
sales'[Total Sales] - [COGS])
RETURN DIVIDE(_NetIncome, SUMX('historical-sales','historical- 
sales'[Sales Qty] * RELATED(Items_List[item_cost])))
```

The return on Investment measure, first I calculate the profit by subtract the cogs from the total sales then use the ROI formula:
ROI = profit/ cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `[COGS]` is the measure, then your `SUMX` has been written wrong. The engine doesn't know on what row it exactly is. That means you have to do a context transition.

Try:

```
ROI = 
VAR _NetIncome = 
   SUMX(
     'historical-sales', 
     'historical sales'[Total Sales] - CALCULATE( [COGS] ) 
   )
RETURN DIVIDE(_NetIncome, SUMX('historical-sales','historical- 
sales'[Sales Qty] * RELATED(Items_List[item_cost])))
```